# How to to use both indexes for ORDER BY and GROUP BY clause?

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySQL tables `article` and `category` and `category_article`.Every article may belongs to more than category and that is my `SQL` query.

```
SELECT * FROM article a
LEFT JOIN category_article ca ON a.id=ca.aid
LEFT JOIN category c ON c.id=ca.cid
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY a.date DESC
WHERE c.status='1'
LIMIT 0,10
```

Using different columns for `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` prevents indexes from using.
So is there another technique that i can use for speeding up this query.

Comment: If each article belongs to at least one category, you could make `INNER JOIN`s instead, this should already be faster.

Comment: Why that GROUP BY? (I see no aggregate functions.)

Comment: Why do you join categories in this query?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? The group by makes the SQL non-deterministic (and is actually invalid SQL) older mysql version will run this, though 5.7+ will not by default. Right now the entire group by is only used to retrieve "just one" category...

Comment: your query as it stands now will return a single arbitrary category from all the categories each article belongs to. It may be a new category every time you submit the query. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: provide an example of raw data and expected result please

Comment: I use group by for controlling the limits

Answer (score 0):

As you are not doing any aggregation you could probably leave out the group by and just order the results by a.ID, a.date and get the same results.  This should result in a faster query execution plan.

```
SELECT * FROM article a
Left JOIN category_article ca ON a.id=ca.aid
Left JOIN category c ON c.id=ca.cid
ORDER BY a.id, a.date DESC
```

Comment: I forgot the limit part lets say that i need the first 10 articles ordered by date that is why i use group by

Comment: Try using mysql 'explain' to asses and then optimise your query execution plan. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html

Comment: i cant optimise if order by and group by use different columns

Comment: You need to try different approaches and compare the qep on each to see exactly when the indexes are used. That is what I mean by optimise. Some approaches that come to mind are a nested subquery or maybe a multi column index. As another user suggested avoiding left joins might improve performance.  Additionally you might try optimising your table statistics using ANALYZE TABLE or assessing whether you are using the right kind of indexes.  Mysql explain will be the key to analysing all this.